# Qual o Link Abreviado pro Stack Overflow em Português?

Tags: novo-recurso, status-pronto, comentários, formatação

Tentei usar um [*Magic Link*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) de comentário pra direcionar um luso-parlante do SO pra cá, mas nada do que tentei funcionou:

```
[pt.se]
[pt.so]
[portugues.se]
```

Isso existe? Ou seria uma *feature request*?

Abri uma [solicitação no Meta principal](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224732/missing-magic-link-for-stack-overflow-in-portuguese), já que é um problema geral na rede.

Comment: [sopt] funciona? Não :(

Comment: `[pt.so]` -> [pt.so] :)

Comment: Testando a novidade: [pt.so]. Yes!

Comment: @Oded Estou acessando e está dando erro, o certo seria pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @Paulo - ooops. Will fix soon. Note to self - use the right domain name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added a `[pt.so]` magic link.

With you in the next build (rev 2014.4.10.1539, meta rev 2014.4.10.2153)

Comment: Bravissimo! Muito obrigado :)

Comment: De nada, @brasofilo

Comment: [pt.so] @Oded the link have a error, correct is pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: @PauloMaciel - fixado!