# Traduzir texto do "magic link" [edit]

Tags: bug, status-pronto, tradução, internacionalização

Entre os [links mágicos](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1009/qual-o-link-abreviado-pro-stack-overflow-em-portugues), há alguns que são muito úteis para compor comentários com orientações novos usuários, como `[about]`, que apontam para o *tour*, `[ask]`, que leva para a página de ajuda sobre como perguntar, e `[help]`, que vai para a home da Central de Ajuda. Esses três são substituídos pelos nomes das respectivas páginas.

Mas `[edit]`, que cria um link para edição do post atual (pergunta ou resposta onde está sendo postado o comentário), gera um link com o texto "edit", em vez de "editar". Vi o @brasofilo dar um jeitinho usando `[edit]ar`, que gera [edit](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1322/edit)ar, mas fica meio feio, não? Tenho usado isso também, mas preferiria que o link viesse com o texto correto em português. É possível?

Comment: [ask] tô testando

Comment: E só agora vc me conta isso?? :p

Comment: O workaround é fazer um link normal para a edição mesmo: `[editar](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/1322/edit)`. Só tem que tomar cuidado em pegar o número do post certo.

Comment: Mas o objetivo do magic link é justamente não precisar ter esse trabalho todo, @GuilhermeBernal!

Comment: Dúvida: Quando isso for corrigido, comentário já criados vão sofrer alteração ou só seria aplicável em novos?

Comment: Não sei, mas vou deixar um teste aqui para a posteridade: [edit] (se no futuro isto aparecer em português, é porque a correção se aplica a comentários antigos; e se procurar, vai achar uns "editarar" perdidos pelo site). @GuilhermeBernal

Comment: Acho que com mais jeitinho é se for **[edit]**: `**[edit]**`

Comment: Please, please: to our Community Manager or another CM, can you explain the admin interface for Magic Links? Is it local, global, who edits it?

Comment: nada de consertarem esse né? :/

Comment: Nada, @Math. Deve ser daquelas coisas que afetariam o sistema todo, acho que não vão mexer. Talvez criar outro só pra gente... e secreto pro resto, hehehe. Esta pergunta tem até uma sinalização minha, em inglês, para chamar a atenção dos devs, e nada.

Comment: Vou propor o feature na próxima semana.

Comment: @Math Boas notícias do Gabe :D

Comment: [Editar] já funciona? [Edit]

Comment: @JorgeB. olha no rodapé da página, estamos no build 2014.7.18.1715, e ele estará disponível no 2014.7.18.1716

Comment: @Math Quando fiz o comentário ainda não tinha visto a resposta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Somehow that was the only magic link that was not localized...

It is now, and you will see it soon, in the next build (rev 2014.7.18.1716).

Comment: Once deployed, [edit] <--- should be correct

Comment: Well, the MLs we've made like "[edit]" will look a weird "editarar". Is there any way to fix that? Maybe it's not a problem at all, but if there's a easy fix then why not?

Comment: @Math your concern are real now...

Comment: @Math - all fixed now.

Comment: @Oded Great! Thanks!